# Changing gnome terminal transparency with a command in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

How can I change the transparency of the Terminal windows in Ubuntu with a command?

I already know about the profile method but want a command so that I can quickly swap between transparent and opaque.

My terminal is GNOME Terminal 2.30.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use gconftool with the key /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_type (you might have to use a different profile name than "Default"):

```
gconftool -s -t string /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_type solid
gconftool -s -t string /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_type transparent
```

This was tested in version 3.0.1, but the command should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to change the transparency in continuous rather than discrete steps, try:

`gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_darkness --type=float 0.50`
with /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_darkness being the **key** and 0.50 being the **value**.