# Mate terminal change background transparency programmatically?

Tags: mate-desktop, mate-terminal

I've decided to experiment with making my life more beautiful by having background images scraped from *flickr* that change every 30 minutes together with transparent terminal and editor windows.

However, this has some downsides. Occasionally the images are too visible and impede editing, so I want to tweak transparency.

Thus I want a quick way to change transparency in my editor (emacs: done) and my terminal (mate-terminal, not-done).

This appears to be possible in *gnome-terminal* ([Changing gnome terminal transparency with a command in Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/changing-gnome-terminal-transparency-with-a-command-in-ubuntu#24618)). My understanding was that mate-terminal was forked from gnome-terminal.

" You can use gconftool with the key /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_type (you might have to use a different profile name than "Default"): "

But I don't seem to be able to find any settings that change when I change background.

```
meld <( { gconftool  -R / | sort ; gsettings list-schemas | xargs -n 1 gsettings list-recursively  | sort  } ) <( { sleep 20 ;  gconftool  -R / | sort ; gsettings list-schemas | xargs -n 1 gsettings list-recursively  | sort  } )
```

## Source code

I tried reading some sort code. This looks like a good starting point: https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-terminal/blob/078d0b1fdac2e50dfa4411b612e78a4be134e47d/src/terminal-screen.c#L1111

The profile looks to get found like so `profile = g_value_get_object (value);` The reference manual for this function call can be found [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Standard-Parameter-and-Value-Types.html#g-value-get-object) but the [documentation for GValue](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Generic-values.html#GValue) seems a little opaque.

Anyway yes, does anyone know enough to get an answer for this?

## Possible lines of attack

- Use *btrfs* snapshots to discover exactly what changed
- Use *strace *to work out what is going on (strace output is a bit noisy because of this being an X application)
- Read the code mode

## Alternatives

- Switch to gnome-terminal. I'm disinclined to do this because something that is unlikely to change. My understanding is that MATE was forked because gnome was changing too fast so this seems like a good choice.
- Switch to another terminal. I'm not open to this. But don't really know which terminal to switch to
- Intelligently render backgrounds to ensure that they are tinted correctly
- Have keybindings that modify the *background* rather than the terminal

Answer (score 1):

`mate-terminal` store it's settings in `dconf`, separate set per each terminal settings profile. So if you have default profile then it will be:

```
$ dconf read /org/mate/terminal/profiles/default/background-type
'solid'
$ dconf read /org/mate/terminal/profiles/default/background-darkness 
0.5
```

First setting for background type - `solid` or `transparent`, and second one for transparency level.

To change transparency settings programmatically you have 2 options:

1. Use single profile and change it's settings via dconf:

   ```
   $ dconf write /org/mate/terminal/profiles/default/background-type "'transparent'"
   $ dconf write /org/mate/terminal/profiles/default/background-type "'solid'"
   ```
2. Create 2 profiles with different settings and choose one when launching terminal:

   ```
   $ mate-terminal --load-config=FILE
   ```